# How to pass a parameter that changes with time to SciLab ode?

Tags: ode, scilab

I'm trying to solve and heat transfer problem using SciLab's ode function. The thing is: one of the parameters changes with time, h(t). 
 [ODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgqNK.png)

My question is: how can I pass an argument to ode function that is changing over time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ode` allows extra function's parameters as list :

> It may happen that the simulator f needs extra arguments. In this
>   case, we can use the following feature. The f argument can also be a
>   list lst=list(f,u1,u2,...un) where f is a Scilab function with
>   syntax: ydot = f(t,y,u1,u2,...,un) and u1, u2, ..., un are extra
>   arguments which are automatically passed to the simulator simuf.

## Extra parameter is a function of t

```
function y = f(t,y,h)
 // define y here depending on t and h(t),eg y = t + h(t)
endfunction

function y = h(t)
 // define here h(t), eg y = t
endfunction

// define y0,t0 and t
y = ode(y0, t0, t, list(f,h)) // this will pass the h function as a parameter
```

## Extra is a vector for which we want to extract the corresponding term.

Since `ode` only compute the solution `y` at `t`. An idea is to look for `Ti < t < Tj` when `ode` performs a computation and get `Hi < h < Hj`.

This is  rather ugly but totally works:

```
function y = h(t,T,H)
  res = abs(t - T)          // looking for nearest value of t in T
  minres = min(res)         // getting the smallest distance
  lower = find(res==minres) // getting the index : T(lower)
  res(res==minres)=%inf     // looking for 2nd nearest value of t in T: nearest is set to inf
  minres = min(res)         // getting the smallest distance
  upper = find(minres==res) // getting the index: T(upper)
  // Now t is between T(lower) (nearest) and T(upper) (farest) (! T(lower) may be > T(upper))
  y = ((T(upper)-t)*H(lower)+(t-T(lower))*H(upper))/(T(upper)-T(lower)) // computing h such as the barycenter with same distance to H(lower) and H(upper)
endfunction

function ydot=f(t, y,h,T,H)
    hi = h(t,T,H)       // if Ti< t < Tj; Hi<h(t,T,H)<Hj
    disp([t,hi])        // with H = T, hi = t
    ydot=y^2-y*sin(t)+cos(t) - hi // example of were to use hi
endfunction

// use base example of `ode`
y0=0; 
t0=0;
t=0:0.1:%pi;
H = t // simple example
y = ode(y0,t0,t,list(f,h,t,H));
plot(t,y)
```

Comment: I've read this help in SciLab and couldn't managed to make it work, but with your example it was easy! This solve 50% of my problem, because now I can solve the direct problem using this, but I still need to work with the inverse problem, and for this I may need another feature that I don't know if SciLab has. Is there a way to pass a parameter as vector that after each time SciLab automatically picks one after another?
Example:
 `t=[1 2 3];  h=[7 8 9];  sol=ode(yo, to, t, list(f,h)) ` So, in this case it will use h=7 for t=1, h=8 for t=2 and so on.

Comment: Improved my answer. Wrote on my phone so it's only a guess. Please tell me if this works !

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. I printed the values of t inside the function y=f(t,h,T)...the values are totally different from the ones passed in the vector t, curiously it never appears the values of t, hence the 'h(find(t==T))' never finds a value. I can have done something wrong, though. The only way i found to make it work was implementing Rung-Kutta, so I had more control over the parameters being passed. But I really appreciate your help. Many thanks, my friend!

Comment: I've an other idea but I need a computer, so I will write it in 2hours. If you still want to pass a vector and get the right value with ode, let me know

Comment: I you still want to use ode, i've may have found a workaround, look answer.

Comment: Yes, I still want it. I'm very busy today, but tomorrow I'll try to implement it!